# Is it possible to render js files with Velocity code inside with Spring MVC and Velocity-Toolbox?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring-mvc, velocity

I'm writing a webapp with Spring MVC, Velocity and AngularJS. I face a problem with I18n strings. 
In html output sometimes translated tags are static so i can use a custom velocity call to put a translated text from a properties files, something like this:

```
<h2>#springMessageText('main.section.title')</h2>
```

But sometimes the text in render dinamically in client using javascript so i have many translations_xx_XX.js files to store those translations:

```
var _i18n = {
  'lang': 'gl-ES',
  'lang.short': 'gl',
  'serverError.message':'Erro no servidor.',
  'yes': 'Sí',
  'no': 'Non',
  ...
}
```

So i load those translations in client with whith a javascript function when needed:

```
myCtrl.i18n['serverError.message'];
```

All works fine but i face the problem that many labels are duplicated in both *.properties files and translations_xx_XX.js files and it's hard to maintain.

So my question: Is there a way to render inside js files using velocity tags, so the translations_xx_XX.js file is filled with translations from *.properties files? Somthing like this:

```
var _i18n = {
  'lang': '#springMessageText("lang")',
  'lang.short': '#springMessageText("lang.short")',
  ...
}
```

Doing this i have to deal only with one source for translation tags.

Edited:

I found where the problem is. Velocity was configured along with Spring MVC in webapp-config.xml:

```
<bean id="velocityConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer">
  <property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/view/"/>
  <property name="velocityProperties">
    <props>
      <prop key="input.encoding">utf-8</prop>
      <prop key="output.encoding">utf-8</prop>
    </props>
  </property>
</bean>

<!-- bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"-->
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityViewResolver">
  <property name="cache" value="true"/>
  <property name="prefix" value=""/>
  <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
  <property name="exposeSpringMacroHelpers" value="true"/>
  <property name="contentType" value="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <property name="toolboxConfigLocation" value="/WEB-INF/velocity-toolbox.xml" />
</bean>
```

So only html files under /view folder are parsed by Velocity. My question is if there is a way to add the same Velocity behaviour to *.js files under /resources folder? Can i define two velocityConfig and two viewResolver?

Comment: I don't get what your actual problem is. What is stopping you from simply creating a velocity template and having it generate the js content you seek?

Comment: I don't know  much about Velocity so i'm unable to tell Velocity to render inside my js files as i do on html files. The example i put renders a js file with this literal content: var _i18n = { 'lang': '#springMessageText("lang")',...}  And i want it to be: var _i18n = { 'lang': 'gl-ES',...} With translations filled from properties files through my springMessageText funciton.

Comment: I can't say much more than what the very rich Velocity documentation clearly explains; only that Velocity does have its design quirks that makes it a less ideal tool to actually generate javascript with. https://robertmassaioli.wordpress.com/2012/06/25/friends-dont-let-friends-write-javascript-in-velocity-templates/ .

Comment: Well, the js file i need to generate is very simple, only a hash of key:value of String on both places. Maybe it's enough for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Possibly you can move the `translations_xx_XX.js` into the Velocity template folder. And the `translations_xx_XX.js` needs to be imported in the `.vm` file.</strike>

**P.S.** This solution assumes that the view is generated using Velocity View Servlet.

*Edited: 05:22AM 28 Aug,2015 IST*

As mentioned in your post, `<property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/view/"/>`, here `view` is Velocity template `folder/directory`. You will have to move the `translations_xx_XX.js` file(s) into this folder. Now you need to use the `.vm` to import the `.js` so that velocity macros could be parsed. e.g.

*page.vm:*

```
<script>
  #parse("translations_xx_XX.js")
</script>
```

> Can i define two viewResolver?

Yes, all you need to do is add `<property name="order" value="<order_no>"/>`, lower order value has a higher priority, e.g.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver">
         <property name="location">
            <value>/WEB-INF/spring-views.xml</value>
         </property>
         <property name="order" value="0" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver">
         <property name="basename" value="spring-views" />
         <property name="order" value="1" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: The problem is that i don't use Velocity templates. Velocity is used along with Sprng MVC.  I've updated my question with more info.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i managed to make it possible.

First of all, you need two view resolvers configured in the Spring web configuration file:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<bean id="velocityConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer">
  <property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/view/"/>
  <property name="velocityProperties">
    <props>
      <prop key="input.encoding">utf-8</prop>
      <prop key="output.encoding">utf-8</prop>
    </props>
  </property>
</bean>

<bean id="htmlViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityViewResolver">
  <property name="order" value="0" />
  <property name="cache" value="true"/>
  <property name="prefix" value=""/>
  <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
  <property name="exposeSpringMacroHelpers" value="true"/>
  <property name="contentType" value="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <property name="toolboxConfigLocation" value="/WEB-INF/velocity-toolbox.xml" />
</bean>

<!-- Resolver velocity for js files to be rendered on server side. Should be included in /view/ to avoid problems with other static content inside /resources/ for example. -->
<bean id="jsViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityViewResolver">
  <property name="order" value="1" />
  <property name="cache" value="true"/>
  <property name="prefix" value=""/>
  <property name="suffix" value=".js"/>
  <property name="exposeSpringMacroHelpers" value="true"/>
  <property name="contentType" value="text/javascript; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <property name="toolboxConfigLocation" value="/WEB-INF/velocity-toolbox.xml" />
</bean>
```

It's very important to notice that you must put the js you want to render inside the resourceLoaderPath defined in the VelocityConfigurer. Also notice that this must not clash with the mvc:resources path to avoid Spring serve your js file statically.

Then create your js file as a normal velocity file (in this case inside the /views/ forder). In my case it declares a hash of translations depending on server locale:

```
var _i18n = {
  'lang': '#springMessageText("lang")',
  'lang.short': '#springMessageText("lang.short")',
  'serverError.message': '#springMessageText("serverError.message")',

  'entities.displayName': '#springMessageText("entities.displayName")',
  ...rest of translations...
};
```

Finally you need to do that that spring web render this view with Velocity so you need to add to a controller one mapping like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/translations.js")
public String getTranslationsJs(HttpServletRequest request, Locale locale) {
    return "/translations";
}
```

This way, when making a reference to this js file on your html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/translations.js"></script>
```

Spring web renders the file using velocity returning a content like this:

```
  var _i18n = {
    'lang': 'en-US',
    'lang.short': 'en',
    'serverError.message': 'Server error.',
    'entities.displayName': 'Company name'
    ...
  };
```